# Trying to return a URL from a JSON file

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

I've been trying to return a URL from a JSON list for a while now. I've tried using various methods but I can't seem to get it to work...
I was wondering how I'd go about returning a value. I haven't really experimented much with JavaScript so I guess I had this coming...

Anyways here is the code:

```js
async function getGithubPicture(username, callback) {
    let data = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/' + username);
    let main = await data.json().then((data) => {
        return data.avatar_url.toString();
    });
    return main;
}

document.getElementById('pfp').src = getGithubPicture('harryuk');
```

So what I want `getGithubpicture` to return a string from the JSON file corresponding with the username `harryuk`, but what gets returned is `[object promise]`, I know this is functioning correctly but I want to function it in a different way and that's where my block is

Comment: try splitting your commands. let main = await data.json(); main= main.avatar_url.toString();

Comment: Thanks, the code looks a lot neater now. My original issue still remains though.

Comment: Your issue is that the variable main got a promise that isn't evaluated at the time of the return. I can't see why this wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async function always return [AsyncFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) object. So it return promise

```
async function getGithubPicture(username, callback) {
    let data = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/' + username);
    let main = await data.json();
    return main.avatar_url.toString();
}

document.getElementById('pfp').src = await getGithubPicture('harryuk');
// or 
getGithubPicture('harryuk').then(url=> document.getElementById('pfp').src = 
url)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Arshpreet, your answer works perfectly. I'll remember this next time.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you don't have the result when you try to assign the value to the image source.
You can try :

```js
function getGithubPicture(username, callback) {
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/' + username)
    .then((response)=>{
     return response.json();
    })
    .then((jsonResponse)=>{
      callback(jsonResponse.avatar_url.toString());
    });
}
function updateAvatar(avatarUrl){
  document.getElementById('pfp').src = avatarUrl;
}
getGithubPicture('harryuk',updateAvatar);
```

```html
<img src="" id="pfp"/>
```